# Android Studio 3.2 Beta 5 Plugins and repositories list empty

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

I'm trying to install a plugin on AS but the JetBrains Plugin list and repository list it's empty...

Is this a expected behavior for this versions, or I found a Bug?

This my system info:

```
Android Studio 3.2 Beta 5
Build #AI-181.5281.24.32.4913314, built on July 25, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b04 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.17.9-200.fc28.x86_64
```

---

Well it is also happening with AS 3.3 Canary 3, so maybe it his expected to be like that... Adding system info:

```
Android Studio 3.3 Canary 3
Build #AI-181.5281.24.33.4884283, built on July 10, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b04 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.17.9-200.fc28.x86_64
```

Comment: This is happening to me too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just tested again with AS 3.2 Beta 5 and the repository was now showing items... So Maybe it was a configuration error within the Android SDK...